# React Native: createBottomTabNavigator header: null not working

Tags: reactjs, react-native

My App.js looks like this which has `StackNavigator`

```
export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <AppStackNavigator />
    );
  }
}


const AppStackNavigator = new StackNavigator({

  LoginScreen: { screen: LoginScreen },
  DashboardScreen: { screen: DashboardScreen },
  ImportantNumberScreen: { screen: ImportantNumberScreen },
  EventListScreen: { screen: EventListScreen },
});
```

I have to create bottom navigation so i am using react-navigation component `createBottomTabNavigator` where i want to set header as null 
so i tried following code

```
static navigationOptions = {
        header: null,//works with createStackNavigator but not with createBottomTabNavigator
    }
```

Also tried

```
export default createBottomTabNavigator({
    HomeScreen: {screen : HomeScreen,navigationOptions:{header:null}},
    GuestCardScreen: GuestCardScreen,
    MoreScreen: MoreScreen,
    StatementScreen: StatementScreen,
});
```

but unfortunately these code not working with `createBottomTabNavigator`

[image]

I am using

> "react-navigation": "^2.17.0"
>
> Node version v10.11.0
>
> npm version v6.4.1

Answer (score 2):

TabBar

```
const MainAppTab = createBottomTabNavigator({
[HOME_STACK]: {
  screen: Home,
},
[NOTIFACATION]: NotificationContainer,
[STINGER]: StingerContainer,
[MESSAGE]: MessageContainer,
[USER_PROFILE]: ProfileContainer
},
},
{
   // settings
});
```

Main Navigator

```
const AppNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  [WELCOME]: {
screen: WelcomeContainer,
},
    // other screens
[MAIN]: {
screen: MainAppTab,
navigationOptions: {
    header: null, <----- this will help you
},
},
}, {
    initialRouteName: WELCOME,
},
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you should set tab bar options like below:

```
const TabNav = createBottomTabNavigator({
  HomeScreen: {screen : HomeScreen},
  GuestCardScreen: GuestCardScreen,
  MoreScreen: MoreScreen,
  StatementScreen: StatementScreen,
});

// just for hide tabbar header
const StackNavForTabs = createStackNavigator({
  tab: TabNav,
}, {
  header: null,
  headerMode: 'none'
});

//your main stack navigator
export default AppStack = createStackNavigator({
 otherStackRoutes: OtherRoute,
 tabStack: StackNavForTabs,
});
```

Comment: Do you have any StackNavigator in your project? If its exist, I updated my answer, please check again.

Comment: Yes, Now i got it but what if i want to put header on particular screen then do i have to put navigationOptions on that particular screen??

Comment: This removed my header from my all `StackNavigator` i want to remove header only from `bottomNavigation` and not from `StackNavigation`

Comment: I am confused how to manage this now, i updated my question please have a look and guide me how to achieve this

Comment: If you don't want to header on your TabNavigator, you should wrap it with StackNavigator. If you check my code carefully, I created StackNavForTabs navigator to just hide tab bar header.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180795/discussion-between-akshay-katariya-and-melih-mucuk).