# Remove Header from top of Stack Navigator in React Native

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I am having difficulties trying to remove the header that appears on the top of my app when using the navigation stack. Any help is much appreciated, as I have looked at similar forums trying to solve this issue, but I could not find a solution:

```js
const NavigationTab = createBottomTabNavigator({


  Home: {
    screen: ScreenOne,
  },

  Explore: {
    screen: ScreenTwo
  },

  SignUp: {
    screen: ScreenThree
  }
});

const Stack = createStackNavigator({


  NavigationTab: NavigationTab,
  ScreenFour: {screen: ScreenFour},

});



const AppContainer = createAppContainer(Stack)

export default AppContainer;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I've currently got the stack navigator set up in a React Native project I've been working on.

```
const MainStackNavigator = createStackNavigator(App_Routes, {
  initialRouteName: 'Base',
  headerMode: 'none',
});
```

Comment: Yes, the options are float, screen or none

Comment: I have tried adding it to my code, but the header still shows.

Comment: Hmm where are you importing createNavigationStack from? Also what version of react-navigation-stack/ react-navigation are you on?

Comment: import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation-stack';

Comment: Also, how do I find out the version?

Comment: Ok so it looks like the bottom tab navigator is whats creating the header, have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/52516640/3251122